# Multiple form submits with form data getting added into a new .php file array

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to make it so that I can still send multiple forms, but have it so each that letter can have unique values instead of the same ones. I need to make it so that I can submit the form and then submit a new one with new values, each time those values to get added into the array inside data.php.

EDIT: I am aware that the best way to do this is with a database. I wanted to know if there is another way, without having a database.

*Apologies for the bad coding, I am still quite new to this.*

**letters.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Домашна Работа 3</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Tahoma;
        }
        
        table, td {
            margin: auto;
            padding: 7px;
            width: 33%;
            border: 2px solid black;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            background: #f0faff;
        }
        
        th {
            font-size: 40px;
            margin: auto;
            padding: 10px;
        }
        
        h1 {
            margin: auto;
            padding: 30px;
            background: #bfeaff;
        }
        
        input {
            margin: 10px;
        }
        
        p {
            font-size: 20px;
            margin: auto;
            padding: auto;
        }
        
        hr {
            margin: 15px;
            padding: auto;
        }
        
        input[type=submit], input[type=reset] {
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            padding-left: 15px;
            padding-right: 15px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="data.php">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <center>
                        <h1>СЪЗДАВАНЕ НА ПИСМО(А)</h1>
                        <label for="countLetters">Колко писма искате да изпратите?</label>
                        <input type="number" placeholder="Мин. 1" id="countLetters" name="countLetters" required><br>
                        <hr>
                        <label for="firstName_Receiver">Име на получател:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="firstName_Receiver" name="firstName_Receiver" required><br>
                        <label for="lastName_Receiver">Фамилия на получател:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="lastName_Receiver" name="lastName_Receiver" required><br>
                        <hr>
                        <p>Съдържания:</p><br>
                        <textarea placeholder="Напр. 'Имаме удоволствието да ви поканим на открито изложение'" id="Context1" name="Context1" rows="6" cols="65" required></textarea><br><br>
                        <textarea placeholder="Напр. 'Бъдете 10 минути преди откриването!'" id="Context2" name="Context2" rows="6" cols="65" required></textarea><br><br>
                        <p>Послепис:</p><br>
                        <textarea placeholder="Напр. 'С уважение'" id="Afterword" name="Afterword" rows="4" cols="40" required></textarea>
                        <hr>
                        <label for="firstName_Sender">Вашето име:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="firstName_Sender" name="firstName_Sender" required><br>
                        <label for="lastName_Sender">Вашата фамилия:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="lastName_Sender" name="lastName_Sender" required><br>
                        <hr>
                        <input type="submit" value="Изпрати" id="Submit" name="Submit">
                        <input type="reset" value="Изчисти">
                    </center>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

**data.php**

```
<?php
$count = $_POST["countLetters"];
$letter = array(
    'fN_R' => array(),
    'lN_R' => array(),
    'C1' => array(),
    'C2' => array(),
    'Aw' => array(),
    'fN_S' => array(),
    'lN_S' => array()
);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    array_push($letter['fN_R'], $_POST["firstName_Receiver"]);
    array_push($letter['lN_R'], $_POST["lastName_Receiver"]);
    array_push($letter['C1'], $_POST["Context1"]);
    array_push($letter['C2'], $_POST["Context2"]);
    array_push($letter['Aw'], $_POST["Afterword"]);
    array_push($letter['fN_S'], $_POST["firstName_Sender"]);
    array_push($letter['lN_S'], $_POST["lastName_Sender"]);
}    
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
{
    echo "Уважаеми (а), " . $letter["fN_R"][$i] . " " . $letter["lN_R"][$i] . "<br>" .
    $letter["C1"][$i] . "<br>" .
    $letter["C2"][$i] . "<br>" .
    $letter["Aw"][$i] . ", " . $letter["fN_S"][$i] . " " . $letter["lN_S"][$i] . "!";
    if ($i + 1 == $count)
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<hr>";
    }
}
```

Comment: To my knowledge ... NO it is not possible as every time new data adds previous ones get deleted.You has to look for database.

Comment: Is it possible to make it without a database. I am aware of the database option, but I wanted to ask if there is another way.

Comment: Sorry bro, if dont know and i would appreciate if i get to know from others